# Yamaha ydp-143 black keys noise problem

Tags: digital-piano

I bought this piano 1,5 years ago. Some of the black keys are making loud noise after release. You can see this on this video

. Could you tell me if I should fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could fix it. It's 2 sponge / foam rails on top and bottom, all along the keyboard range. Just replace both of them. They dampen the sound of the keys being played down, and the key-return up. That is just how part of the "mechanism" works on entry digital pianos.

I've done it twice but must admit that while both times it was much better, it will get back to the same state, maybe even quicker.

The biggest issues I found were:

- Cleaning the old foam adhesive off the keyboard (I used an old credit card). And be prepared it might take some time.
- Lifting the piano in place, just get someone else to lift with you.

I did all the work needed on the floor: lots of space. I definitely used this video:
[The Simple Repair of a Yamaha Clavinova to reduce Keyboard Noise](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j7IXhThEpV4) at least once.
Also check out the comments there.

It seems to be called a "YAMAHA ARIUS/YDP/DGX GHL type upper & lower felt kit" but obviously check with supplier.